Firebase Listener doesnt work on safari but works on chrome
I am making a time table that users can store locally using Shared Preferences in flutter. When an admin makes an update in firestore, I want the changes to be updated locally as well (in Shared Preferences). To accomplish this, I set up a listener on my home page so that every time it detects a change, it updates shared preferences locally. The app is hosted using firebase hosting. When an update occurs and the app is on chrome, the listener detects the change and updates the local storage, however when I am on safari, I get an error stating
[Error] Fetch API cannot load https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Listen/channel?gsessionid=g5TPNIasqETmn-9w8I8T1GS3lhFGHFAMut1TOu12PX8&VER=8&database=projects%2Fmasjid2024-79d97%2Fdatabases%2F(default)&RID=rpc&SID=HBdn6q7fqYmgOqyX3ORfUQ&AID=94&CI=0&TYPE=xmlhttp&zx=fv87ij55oyip&t=1 due to access control checks.
    (anonymous function) (firebase-firestore.js:1:33574)
    (anonymous function) (firebase-firestore.js:1:49972)
    ic (firebase-firestore.js:1:21180)
    Md (firebase-firestore.js:1:40269)
    (anonymous function) (firebase-firestore.js:1:51840)
    ub (firebase-firestore.js:1:17048)"

When I click the link, it shows:
400. That’s an error.

Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request. Unknown SID That’s all we know.

I have read other queries related to CORS posted but I'm still confused... firebase docs don't mention having to tinker with CORS to enable listeners
This is how Im using the listener(other code has been stripped out):
late StreamSubscription<QuerySnapshot>
      _updatesSubscription; // Listener subscription

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _listenForUpdates(); // Start listening for updates
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _updatesSubscription
        .cancel(); // Cancel the listener when the widget is disposed
    super.dispose();
  }

void _listenForUpdates() {
    _updatesSubscription = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('updates')
        .snapshots()
        .listen((snapshot) {
      for (var doc in snapshot.docChanges) {
        if (doc.type == DocumentChangeType.modified) {
            String updatedMasjidId = doc.doc.id;
            //this updates the timetable in shared preferences
            await UserSettingsService.storePrayerTimesForCurrentMonth([
              updatedMasjidId
            ], [
              {'name': updatedMasjidId, 'id': updatedMasjidId}
            ]);
            print('!!Update occurred for masjidId: $updatedMasjidId');
        }
      }
    });
  }

The problem is: This works on chrome and on iOS Emulators but does not work on safari.

I tried to follow a few different tutorials for listeners, but alas, they don't work on Safari. As a slightly more expensive workaround, I decided to use a lastUpdated value, which is updated in Firebase for every update. When a user refreshes, this value is fetched and compared with a locally stored value (in Shared Preferences) and if they're not equal, I call my update function. This is more expensive in terms of firebase reads and writes since a listener does not add to a read unless the value in Firebase has changed. This work around is also not "realtime." Any help will be appreciated :)
